# What is the equivalent of ~/.cache on macOS?

Tags: library

I'm writing a tool that needs to cache files that are supposed to be hidden from the uninformed user and persist across reboots. On Linux, I am putting these files in `~/.cache`. What's the equivalent of that on the mac?

Can I just use `~/.cache`? I also read about `~/Library/Application Support` and `~/Library/Cache`, but I'm finding a lot of contradictory information.

Comment: Is your program a command line tool or a GUI application?

Comment: @fed It's a gui application, but it also has a cli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right place to store such files is "Library/Caches" (either in ~ or in the app sandbox, depending on whether or not your app is sandboxed).

Apple documents this fact here:

[File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Especially take note of this quote:

> Use this directory to write any app-specific support files that your
>   app can re-create easily. Your app is generally responsible for
>   managing the contents of this directory and for adding and deleting
>   files as needed.

Comment: Note that your app should generally create its own subdirectory under Library/Caches, named with the application's bundle identifier, and store its files in that subdirectory. Look in your ~/Library/Caches directory for examples.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Sure, that's the same in ~/.cache on proper unix systems. But thanks for reminding me. ;)

Comment: @NeoTheThird macOS is actually a Unix systems. It's no more or less "proper" than other Unix systems.